# Laravel non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I create simple Laravel project. In blog view I have pages index (where is first page of last 5 blogs), Edit, Show, and Create. Now, all working fine if I create new Blog from database (edit/delete and show/read). But I can't create new blog from site. Do you see problem?

BlogControllor

```
/**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('blog.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'naslov'=>'Required',
            'slug'=>'Required|alpha_dash|min:5|max:255|unique:blogs,slug',
            'opis'=>'Required',
            'tekst'=>'Required',
            'upload_slike' => 'sometimes|image'
        ]);

        $blog = new Blog;
        $blog->naslov = $request->naslov;
        $blog->slug = $request->slug;
        $blog->opis = $request->opis;
        $blog->tekst = $request->tekst;

        //Sacuvaj novu sliku za blog post
        if ($request->hasFile('upload_slike')) {
            $image = $request->file('upload_slike');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $location = public_path('slike/' . $filename);
            Image::make($image)->resize(800, 400)->save($location);

            $blog->image = $filename;
        }

        $blog->save();
        return redirect('blog');
    }
```

Route

```
Route::resource('blog', 'BlogController');
```

Button on index page for create new Blog

```
<a href="{{ route('blog.create') }}" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">Dodaj novu vest</a>
```

Page create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.bez-sidebar')

<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: 'link image',
            menubar: false
         });
    </script>

@section('content')
    {!! Form::open(['url'=>'blog','class'=>'form-horizontal', 'files' => true]) !!}
    <div class="">
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('naslov', 'Naslov', ['class'=>'control-label col-md-2']) !!}
            <div class="col-md-10">
                {!! Form::text('naslov', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Unesi naslov']) !!}
                {!! $errors->has('naslov')?$errors->first('naslov'):'' !!}
            </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('slug', 'Alias:', ['class'=>'control-label col-md-2']) !!}
            <div class="col-md-10">
                {!! Form::text('slug', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'required' => '', 'minlenght' => '5', 'maxlenght' => '255', 'placeholder'=>'Unesi alias link za post']) !!}
                {!! $errors->has('slug')?$errors->first('slug'):'' !!}
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('opis', 'Opis', ['class'=>'control-label col-md-2']) !!}
            <div class="col-md-10">
                {!! Form::text('opis', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ovde upisite kratak opis vesti']) !!}
                {!! $errors->has('opis')?$errors->first('opis'):'' !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('tekst', 'Tekst', ['class'=>'control-label col-md-2']) !!}
            <div class="col-md-10">
                {!! Form::textarea('tekst', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Ovde upisite celu vest']) !!}
                {!! $errors->has('tekst')?$errors->first('tekst'):'' !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                {{ Form::label('upload_slike', 'Ubacite sliku:')}}
                {{ Form::file('upload_slike') }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                {!! Form::submit('Sačuvaj', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@stop
```

And this error

[image]

Comment: can you post the show method and show view

Comment: Here is github [GITHUB Project](https://github.com/Alexaidzuo/laravel)
I found error but don't know how to fix. If I remove first route, then all is working but blog posts not show slugs, only id.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the image shows that the error is occurring when you're opening a form tag to delete. Check line 5 in the screenshot you took.

Are you including a delete function on your create screen; perhaps in the extended view `layouts.bez-sidebar`? If you are then that could be why `$blog->id` is causing a `trying to get property of non object` error.

Comment: Huh, this is a problem but I don't know how to resolve. Create function return on blog.create page. But it's not working, this going on show.blade page. When I change code from create to show, I can create new blog but then can't read blog because again reading a show file where is my code for create. I try to delete storage but nothing happen...